# Subtract 2 different sized 2D arrays to produce a 3D array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two 2D arrays, one **M** is 2000x3 and the other **N** is 20x3 (sets of x,y,z coords). I would like to subtract **N** from **M** to produce a 3D array 2000x20x3. Currently I get a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2000,3) (20,3)

A more simple example as a working exercise

```
M = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[3,1,1],[4,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,1],[3,2,1],[4,2,1]])
N = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])

M.shape = (8,3)
N.shape = (2,3)
```

I wish to do A=M-N to produce an 8x2x3 array, where for each value 1->M, there are N sets of differences in the x,y,z coordinates.

In other words:

```
A = array([[[1,1,1],[0,1,1]],[[2,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[3,1,1],[2,1,1]],[[4,1,1],[3,1,1]],[[1,2,1],[0,2,1]]...])
```

Is this possible, and if so how? Preferably without the use of any for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
A = M[:,None]-N

A.shape
# (8, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway , is it possible to extend this to a 3D array - 2D array to produce a 4D array, so that if M was now 200x10x3 instead of 2000x3 I could produce a 200x10x20x3 array

Comment: use `M[:, :, None]` instead

Comment: or `M[..., None]` for a generic case of n dimensions